# Linking to text-only HTML "go to line"

Tags: java, html, svn

I have a question but I'm pretty sure the answer is no, so I'm open to ideas to solve my problem.

The problem: I have a program with two versions of code, an online live/production version and a local development/test version. It's a Java Web Start Swing Desktop app. I have setup an error logging system that sends me an email with the stack trace of the error. But, since the local dev/test version is always different from the live version, I have to look at the code that is on the live version to get to the exact line of the error. So, I've setup an SVN which I commit to whenever I update the live program.

I'd like to, in the error email, link directly to the line of that threw the error so that I can just click the link in the stack trace. The stack trace tells me the file + line number. I can access my SVN repository through http, so I can view the code as a text-only no HTML page. But I cannot put anchors in these code pages (`<a name="">`). The code pages are text-only, no HTML (otherwise I'd just put an anchor on every line with the line#).

The question is this: Is there any way to "jump to line #" in a text-only no-HTML page? If I link to the right code file, is there a way I can also jump to a line in that file without `<a name="">` ?

If anyone knows of any good SVN viewer web apps that can plug into my existing SVN that would be welcome to. Hopefully I was clear enough presenting the problem so that it makes sense. I've googled around but I can't find anything. Any solutions you guys may have would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Your description makes sense, but how you're managing your code (especially the part where you don't commit to SVN until after you've put new code in production) sounds broken.

Comment: I am alone in the projects I work on so the SVN was, at first, just for an online backup of my projects. I also do regular backups of my system of course.

If I had others on my team, obviously, things would be much different.